# Вызов MainActivity.this из класса не MainActivity. Как?

Tags: java, android

пытаюсь вызвать MainActivity.this .. но он подчёркивается красным и не хочет подставляться. Как к нему обратить? Представляю код:

```
public class Timer {

    private CountDownTimer currentTimer;

    AlertDialog.Builder builder;

    public Timer(long millisInFuture, final long countDownInterval, final ITimerCallback callback) {

        currentTimer = new CountDownTimer(millisInFuture, countDownInterval) {
            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                long time = millisUntilFinished / 1000;
                callback.ontTimerNewValue(String.valueOf(time));
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {

                callback.ontTimerNewValue("ОК");

                builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                builder.setTitle("Важное сообщение!")
```

Суть в том что я так понял что тут такое обращение не является context. Решения сколько пытался найти, ничего не работает. Помогите кто сможет. Спасибо!

Comment: Объясните, зачем вам вызывать активити в таймере? Подчеркивается красным из-за того что вы в классе Таймера обращаетесь к классу MainActivity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Передавайте `Context` через параметр в конструкторе:

```
public class Timer {

private CountDownTimer currentTimer;
private Context context;

AlertDialog.Builder builder;

public Timer(long millisInFuture, final long countDownInterval, final ITimerCallback callback, Context context) {
    this.context=context;
    currentTimer = new CountDownTimer(millisInFuture, countDownInterval) {
        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            long time = millisUntilFinished / 1000;
            callback.ontTimerNewValue(String.valueOf(time));
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {

            callback.ontTimerNewValue("ОК");

            builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
            builder.setTitle("Важное сообщение!")
```

Answer (score 3):

Если Вам необходимо что-то сделать в активити после какого-то события в таймере - сделайте callback, реализуйте метод callback'a в активити (то что вы хотели делать в самом таймере). Сущность класса Timer не должна ничего решать проверять и делать внутри себя, эта сущность делает конкретную задачу и дергает методы callback'a.

В ITimerCallback добавьте отдельный метод onTimerFinish() - и дергайте его в методе onFinish - самого таймера. В активити создавайте свой диалог.